# Flashlight widget does not turn off

Tags: android, camera, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

I have created everything necessary for my widget to exist and function. Even so at the first click, t does what it is supposed to but then image gets changed and says problem, and does not function. I want it to open flash and then close it.
Help will be much appreciated.

`FlashlightWidgetProvider`

```
public class FlashlightWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

       @Override
       public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                       int[] appWidgetIds) {

               Intent receiver = new Intent(context, FlashlightWidgetReceiver.class);
               receiver.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
               receiver.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
               PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, 0);

               RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                               R.layout.flash_widget);
               views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

               appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

       }
}
```

`FlashlightWidgetReceiver`

```
public class FlashlightWidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static boolean isLightOn = false;
        private static Camera camera;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.flash_widget);

                if(isLightOn) {
                        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.off);
                } else {
                        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.on);
                }

                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,     FlashlightWidgetProvider.class),
                                                                                 views);

                if (isLightOn) {
                        if (camera != null) {
                                camera.stopPreview();
                                camera.release();
                                camera = null;
                                isLightOn = false;
                        }

                } else {
                        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
                        camera = Camera.open();

                        if(camera == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                                // Set the torch flash mode
                                Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
                                param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                                try {
                                        camera.setParameters(param);
                                        camera.startPreview();
                                        isLightOn = true;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_flash, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please very carefully explain what it is supposed to do, and what it is doing, and how that is different than what it is supposed to do. Without knowing what it is supposed to do, there's not alot we can do...

Comment: It sounds like you are saying it crashes. If this is the case then please post the logcat.

Comment: @codeMagic  Well, the widget get's created and work's only on the first click, after that it says something like problem loading widget were the image was supposed to be, so basically it doesn't close the flash that has opened. I want to open and close the flashlight through this widget. Oh and..  there is no `logcat` for the crash

Comment: Please see my answer and vote up if this was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the button resource refers to an ImageView and not a regular Button. I just tried this out at first with a Button in my layout file and I was getting the same problem where the widget would basically crash and remove itself from the home screen. When I changed button to be an ImageView in the layout file, the code now works.

I did modify the code a bit from yours, so in case that doesn't work by itself, here is the updated FlashlightWidgetProvider:

```
public class FlashlightWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, getClass()));

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, FlashlightWidgetReceiver.class);
            broadcastIntent.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                                                                     0,
                                                                     broadcastIntent,
                                                                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.flashlight);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.flashButton, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to register the widget provider and receiver correctly in the manifest (replacing the relevant pieces with your own, of course):

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.stackoverflowtester.widget.FlashlightWidgetProvider"
        android:label="Flashlight" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/flashlight_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.stackoverflowtester.widget.FlashlightWidgetReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="COM_FLASHLIGHT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!, I must admit it would take me a while to notice!